# What does this Dota 2 error mean?

Tags: dota-2

[image]

I opened and ran Dota 2 earlier today with no issues. Now I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the virtual method 
 `InstallSchemaClassBinding` of one of the schema bindings from `libschemasystem.dylib` has a registration error because of a local class not locally-scoped.

Although you didn't ask for a fix, I would suggest a clean reinstall.

To fix this manually, you'd need to bypass the anti-data tampering code, which I would not recommend if you do not have RE experience.